# Carbon's TISInputSourceRef Memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, macos-carbon

I'm working with `TISInputSourceRef` in a cocoa project (with ARC) and I can't figure out why the profiler is reporting a memory leak.

The Leak:

[image: memory leak]

The Code:

**InputSource**

```
+ (NSDictionary *)current {
    TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    NSDictionary *build =  @{
                           @"name":   (__bridge NSString*)TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyLocalizedName),
                           @"layout": (__bridge NSString*)TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceID)
                           };
    CFRelease(source);
    return build;
}
```

**UserDefaultsManager** (*actual call*)

```
+ (void)registerDefaults {
    NSDictionary *currentInputSource = [InputSource current];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{
                                                                  kDefaultLayout: @{@"layout": currentInputSource[@"layout"]}
                                                              }];
}
```

I tried using `CFBridgingRelease` instead of `__bridge`, copying `currentInputSource[@"layout"]` instead of just assigning it and merging both methods with no luck.

How can I fix this leak? (or...should I?)

Thanks!